# Shortening line segments in Matplotlib plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is it possible to shorten line segments in a matplotlib plot to produce an image like the one below, where the line segments do not completely reach the point markers?

[image: Plot with shortened edges]

Comment: This question is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498702/custom-plot-linestyle-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the following stupid way, but for me it works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 3, 2, 5, 3, 1]
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x,y,'b-')
plt.plot(x,y,'wo', markersize=25, markeredgecolor = 'w')
plt.plot(x,y,'bo', markersize=7, markeredgecolor = 'w')
plt.show()
```

Comment: That works fine as long as you only have one plot.  If several plots overlap, they can interfere with each other.  There does not seem to be another way that would be reasonably simple, though.