# Matplotlib: Markers surrounded by white space

Tags: python, matplotlib

This is a plot from a [2009 paper (PDF)](http://www2009.org/proceedings/pdf/p801.pdf).

[image: Plot from]

- What software was used to draw this?
- How can I achieve the same type of drawing the markers surrounded by white space with matplotlib?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498702/custom-plot-linestyle-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably achieve this type of plot with several different plotting packages. To get something similar in matplotlib, try setting up the markers as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# random data to stand in
x1 = 0.8+0.1*np.random.rand(25)
x2 = 0.3+0.2*np.random.rand(25)
# customise the marker properties
plt.plot(x1, color='g', marker='s', mec='w', mfc='g', mew='3', ms=8)
plt.plot(x2, color='b', marker='s', mec='w', mfc='b', mew='3', ms=8)
plt.show()
```

See the [plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) and [line2D](http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) docs for more information on the properties that you can modify.

Comment: This seems to be a good "hack", but as pointed out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498702/, this does not work very well if multiple lines overlap, or if markers are close to one another. There is yet another hacky solution at the link - but is there really no simple way to get this to work?