# custom marker with lines skipping the marker region

Tags: python, matplotlib, line, markers

We can customize markers according to

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True # enable latex support
mpl.style.use('fivethirtyeight')   # gray background

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(
    range(0,10,2),
    range(0,10,2),
    marker="$abc$",
    markersize=30
)
```

which gives

[image]

How do we make the line skip the region behind each custom marker?

(Without manually adding/subtracting from the individual points)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a second marker with a white filling.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(
    range(0,10,2),
    range(0,10,2),
    marker="o",
    markersize=30,
    markerfacecolor = 'white',
    markeredgecolor = 'white',
    color = 'blue'
)
plt.plot(
    range(0,10,2),
    range(0,10,2),
    marker="$abc$",
    markersize=30,
    linestyle = 'none',
    color = 'blue'
)
```

[image]

Edit: But this does not work with a custom background.
To achieve that, you can adjust the `markeredgewidth` to be a little larger than your custom markers.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
plt.plot(
    range(0,10,2),
    range(0,10,2),
    marker="$abc$",
    markersize=30,
    markeredgewidth=6,
    mec='white',
    color = 'blue'
)
plt.plot(
    range(0,10,2),
    range(0,10,2),
    marker="$abc$",
    markersize=30,
    linestyle = 'none',
    color = 'blue'
)
```

[image]

Similar question [Custom plot linestyle in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498702/custom-plot-linestyle-in-matplotlib)

Comment: The custom background issue you mentioned can be fixed by setting the circle color not to `white`, but to the figure facecolor `plt.rcParams['figure.facecolor']`.